# Finding the bad record in ssis while loading the data

Tags: ssis

I have a derived column transformation and I am getting a runtime error division by zero.

I have more that 10,000 records in my source file and I do not know which record is causing the division by zero record.

Can some one help me to find out the bad record.

Comment: What's the formula for your derived column?

Comment: Why don't you modify your SSIS to handle the error, instead of trying to find it in the file?   Whatever you are going to do when you find it, just do it with code.

Answer (score -1):

[Line Red SSIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFvc8.png)

[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hoo5a.png)

Save the record with errors in a table with red line